# Select Layer By Location to feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

What is the best way to convert the Feature Layer output of Select Layer By Location to Feature Class in ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Copy Features (Data Management)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) tool as the final step in your model. This will copy the results into a feature class.

Comment: is it better than feature class to feature class? what other options are there?

Comment: not sure, try them both, i always use Copy Features